# Drawing curves without arrows using xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, arrow-curve

Could you tell me how to remove the arrows of the curves using `xy-pic`? I didn't find the solution in `xy-guide`. Thanks advance for your help.
[image]
[image]

Comment: As @egreg had mentioned on deleted answer, use `\ar@{-}`.

Comment: Sorry i can only use it to draw a straight l.

Comment: As below, to curve, use `@/^/` or `@/_/` also.

Comment: ...it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
1\ {\circ} \ar@{}@/^/[r] \ar@{}@/_/[r]
& {\circ}\ 1
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `@{}` will make an invisible arrow, no draw pattern.